# Show that V is a strong limit in second-order terms

Tags: set-theory, second-order-logic

Let $X, Y$ be two proper classes. We say that the power of $X$ is equinumerous to $Y$ iff there is a relation $R$ with $domain(R) = Y$ and $range(R) = X$ such that (i) $\forall Z \subseteq X \exists y \in Y R_y = Z$ (where $R_y$ is $\{x : <y ,x> \in R\}$), and (ii) $\forall y_1 , y_2 \in Y \ (y_1 \neq y_2 \rightarrow R_{y_1} \neq R_{y_2})$. (So R codes a ''bijection'' from Y to the ''powerclass'' of X)

My question is: does KM - Global Choice prove the following statement (*) (which basically says that $V$ cannot be reached by taking ''power'' of any class smaller than it)?

(*) If there is no injection from $V$ to $X$, then the power of $X$ is not equinumerous to $V$.

(Since Global Choice implies that all proper classes are equinumerous, this is not an interesting statement given GC.)

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, for sets, $V$ is fully determined by the sets of ordinals it contains. I think that should imply that the "power class" of the ordinals is already bigger than $V$. And since any proper class maps onto the class of ordinals, the power class of any proper class is at least as large as the power class of the ordinals. Consequently, if $X$ is a proper class, then it just has too many subclasses. On the other hand, if by "power class" you mean all the sets included in the class, the first sentence already show what's what.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the reply. So by ''V is fully determined by the sets of ordinals it contains'', do you just mean every set is in bijective with an ordinal?

Comment: No, if M and N are two models of ZF with the same sets of ordinals and one of them satisfies AC, then M=N. In other words, sets of ordinals determine a model of ZFC, start to finish.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. So why does it imply there is no such relation $R$ from $V$ to $Ord$ defined as above?

Comment: Because you're asking about proper subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the case.

The counterargument is exactly along the lines Asaf suggested. If $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ then there is a definable-over-$M$ class surjection from the class of sets of ordinals to $M$ itself. Basically, with a set of ordinals we can "code" arbitrary initial segments of the cumulative hierarchy. In detail, for a set $u$ say that a **code for $u$** is a triple $(\alpha,R,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ is some ordinal, $R$ is a binary relation on $\alpha$ such that $(\alpha;R)\cong V_\gamma$ for some $\gamma$ with $u\in V_\gamma$, and the image of $\beta$ under the unique isomorphism $(\alpha;R)\cong V_\gamma$ is $u$ itself. By appropriate tuple-juggling, we can replace codes with sets of ordinals.

The point is that if global choice fails, there is no injection from $V$ to $Ord$. However, running the above idea with $M=V$ shows - informally speaking - that the powerclass of $Ord$ is at least as big as $V$.

Note that there's some subtlety around the notion of "powerclass" here: are we talking about the *collection of all subclasses* of a given class, or the *collection of all sub**sets*** of a given class? Call these the "big powerclass" and "small powerclass" respectively. The argument above gives a strong negative answer to your question: although $V$ doesn't inject into $Ord$, already the small powerclass of $Ord$ is as big as $V$.

Comment: This is really helpful. I two more questions if you don't mind. How do we know every $V_\gamma$ is isomorphic to some $(\alpha, R)$?  Can you say more about the tuple-juggling? Thank you!

Comment: @user123 Every $V_\gamma$ is isomorphic to some $(\alpha,R)$ since each $V_\gamma$ is well-orderable: fix some bijection $f:V_\gamma\rightarrow\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ (no reason not to use $\alpha=\vert V_\gamma\vert$) and let $R$ be "$\in$ pushed along $f$." Note that this uses only (set-sized) choice, not global choice. As to the tuple-juggling, one thing we can do is represent $(\alpha,R,\beta$) by $\{\alpha\}\times (R\times\{\beta\})$ ; the latter is a genuine set of ordinals, and this representation is injective.